# Can't open chat logs in %appdata%

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I open %appdata%.minecraft and then go to the file logs and open them, I see random letters.  What's wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log files are compressed/archived in a format called [**gzip**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip). To read them you'll need a decompressor/unarchiver that understands gzip files. [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is what I use — it's easy to install and [free](http://www.7-zip.org/).